# Javascript using ajax jquery and json not working with IE or chrome help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have this code that is being ignored by i.e. ive set alerts throughout the code and i've pin point the error being the ajax call

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>Website</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

         $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo",
                                        success: function(data){
                                            ...code
        }
        });
</script>..body.. etc...
```

The code works perfectly on firefox.. however
the $.ajax({}); call is completely ignored in IE and Chrome.. Anyone know why? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Well first thing is you are missing your script tags... `<script type="javascript"></script>`

Comment: Is this code running from geonames.org?

Comment: i have my script tags.. i didnt put them on here.. sorry. and yes its running from geonames.org

Answer (score 4):

Are you missing `<script>` tags, and, you know, jQuery? Also, since this is a cross-site request, make sure you're actually handling this as jsonp correctly.

Without posting your actual code I think that's the best we can do.

Comment: I've tried using crossDomain: true, but that does not fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I can only add to what Michael Haren has already said that what you get from this URL is:

`{"status":{"message":"the daily limit of 30000 credits demo has been exceeded. Please throttle your requests or use the commercial service.","value":18}}`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you're missing the script tags as well as the actual path to the jquery file, and you need to wrap your ajax call in with document ready so...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> // Latest jquery from google
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        // -- Your Code Here

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell add `&callback=?` at the end of the URL.

```
http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?...&username=demo&callback=?
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will prevent the ajax from working in Chrome/Safari but still allow it to work in Firefox is leaving out the `dataType` field of the ajax command. For instance:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo",
    success: function(data){
        var jsonArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(jsonArray.status.message);
    }
});
```

will output the `value` element of the JSON array returned from that URL **ONLY** if ran in Firefox. To get this ajax to work in Chrome you must include the `dataType` field and remove the `jQuery.parseJSON` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Get',
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        var jsonArray = data;
        alert(jsonArray.status.message);
    }
});
```

If this is left out or you try to do it the other way it will appear as it is skipping over your ajax all together. I hope this fixes your problem.